# Oracle Spatial search query error for SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE (lat/long based)

Tags: database, oracle, geospatial, oracle-spatial

I need to perform location based search based on latitude and longitude pairs, to find out the near by locations of stores within a radius/distance of given KMs.

- I am to use (for certain) Oracle's SDO_GEOMETRY for searching the locations.
- Also, the table structure are parent-child based such that store address (zip, lat/long) is in parent table but store details (name, contact, etc) are in the child table.
- This is to make sure that we do not have redundant data (as multiple store can have same lat/long and by some dark magic same address)

I have the following scenario (tables provided):

Version - **Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0**

- Table: STORE_LOCATION

```
CREATE TABLE STORE_LOCATE
(
    ID                  NUMBER                 DEFAULT STORE_LOCATE.nextval,
    POSTAL_CODE         VARCHAR2(18)           NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS             VARCHAR2(382)          NOT NULL,
    GEO_LOCATION        SDO_GEOMETRY           NOT NULL
);
```

- Table: STORE_DETAIL

```
CREATE TABLE STORE_DETAIL
(
    ID                    NUMBER                   DEFAULT STORE_DETAIL_SEQ.nextval,
    STORE_CODE            VARCHAR2(20)             NOT NULL,
    STORE_NAME            VARCHAR2(150)            NOT NULL,
    IS_ACTIVE             NUMBER(3)                DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    fk_store_locate_id  INT                        NOT NULL. -- FK to ID of parent
);
```

I have inserted data in parent as:

```
INSERT INTO STORE_LOCATE (ZIP, ADDRESS, GEO_LOCATION) VALUES
  ('567875', '84 Paddar Road', 
     SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE (80.34234431,26.12354422, NULL), NULL, NULL));
```

Likewise, child table has entries:

```
INSERT INTO STORE_DETAIL (STORE_CODE, STORE_NAME, FK_STORE_LOCATION_ID) VALUES
  ('ST01', 'STORE 1', 1);
```

- So, now when a user shares his location to me (lat/long), I need to search all nearby locations of stores within a specified radius.

I tried the following query, but I am getting error with this:

```
SELECT  
   s.store_code,
   s.store_name,
   loc.zip,
   loc.address,
   loc.geo_location
FROM store_detail s, 
   store_locate loc
where MDSYS.SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(loc.geo_location,
(MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, 
   MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(80.21456732,26.23117864, NULL) ,NULL, NULL)), 
     'distance=1000 unit=KM') = 'TRUE';
```

Getting the below error:

```
ORA-29900: operator binding does not exist
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE'
29900. 00000 -  "operator binding does not exist"
*Cause:    There is no binding for the current usage of the operator.
*Action:   Change the operator arguments to match any of the existing
           bindings or add a new binding to the operator.
```

I am breaking my head around this for a while now but in vain.

Ref:

- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIID-751?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18750/xe_locator.htm#XELOC562

**Q's:**

- Is this the correct way to perform location search on Oracle SQL?
- Is there any other way if the above is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of syntax errors in your code (`POSTAL_CODE` called `ZIP`, etc)
Here is the corrected example (I also removed the sequences for simplicity)

```
CREATE TABLE STORE_LOCATE (
    ID                  NUMBER                 primary key,
    POSTAL_CODE         VARCHAR2(18)           NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS             VARCHAR2(382)          NOT NULL,
    GEO_LOCATION        SDO_GEOMETRY           NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE STORE_DETAIL (
    ID                    NUMBER                   primary key,
    STORE_CODE            VARCHAR2(20)             NOT NULL,
    STORE_NAME            VARCHAR2(150)            NOT NULL,
    IS_ACTIVE             NUMBER(3)                DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    fk_store_locate_id    INT                      NOT NULL references STORE_LOCATE
);
INSERT INTO STORE_LOCATE (ID, POSTAL_CODE, ADDRESS, GEO_LOCATION) VALUES (1, '567875', '84 Paddar Road', SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE (80.34234431,26.12354422, NULL), NULL, NULL));
INSERT INTO STORE_DETAIL (ID, STORE_CODE, STORE_NAME, FK_STORE_LOCATE_ID) VALUES (1001,'ST01', 'STORE 1', 1);
commit;
```

Here is running your query:

```
SELECT  
   s.store_code,
   s.store_name,
   loc.postal_code,
   loc.address,
   loc.geo_location
FROM store_detail s, store_locate loc
where SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(
  loc.geo_location,
  SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, 
    SDO_POINT_TYPE(80.21456732,26.23117864, NULL),NULL, NULL
  ), 
  'distance=1000 unit=KM'
) = 'TRUE';

STORE_ STORE_NAME POSTAL ADDRESS              GEO_LOCATION(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES
------ ---------- ------ -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ST01   STORE 1    567875 84 Paddar Road       SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(80.3423443, 26.1235442, NULL), NULL, NULL)

1 row selected.
```

The error you get probably means Oracle Spatial is not or incorrectly installed in your database. What exact database version do you use ?

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Those queries really need a spatial index on the GEO_LOCATION column. Without one, the query is rejected in versions up to 12.1. From 12.2 and later, the query will run, but will be very slow as soon as the number of locations goes above a few 100s. Once you go into the 100000 or more, it will be *very* slow.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/indexing-querying-spatial-data.html#GUID-07129836-0DAE-4BCC-B290-942C456AE2EA for details

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry for ZIP. Apart from that I had tried multiple syntax but posted this one. Was there any syntax error in search query? I only see a bracket removed. Let me know!

Comment: Version - Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Your syntax is correct. I just laid it out a bit differently for readability (a matter of taste) and corrected the differences in column names. It should work (and works for me). If it does not on your database, I can only think that something is wrong with your spatial installation

Comment: Hold on. Something comes to my mind. How do you connect to the database - which user ? Make sure you connect as a regular user. Not SYSTEM. Definitely not SYS. Using SYS has side effects that could explain what you see

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Yes I am connecting as normal user (no admin rights or system rights)
I suspect it has something related to installation. I'll be discussing internally with team. Thanks again!

Comment: Oracle locator is installed: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL340
Is this correct for the query I am performing?